# How to unselect a selected table row upon second click/selection in javaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

On my JavaFX table, when I click on a row, it selects that row. Now when I click for the second time on same row which was previously selected, I want to deselect that particular row. Is it possible ? Please share some  example code, if its possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below piece of code worked for this requirement.

```
tableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>>() {  
        @Override  
        public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> tableView2) {  
            final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();  
            row.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {  
                @Override  
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {  
                    final int index = row.getIndex();  
                    if (index >= 0 && index < tableView.getItems().size() && tableView.getSelectionModel().isSelected(index)  ) {
                        tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                        event.consume();  
                    }  
                }  
            });  
            return row;  
        }  
    });
```

Used the same Person class from oracle's table view example. Original answer was given by @James_D in oracle's forum.

Comment: This implementation unselects all selected items. To unselect only one item, use `tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(index);`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can choose anything invalid as the index. Generally `-1` is preferred

```
table.getSelectionModel().select(-1);
```

which calls the int `select`. Alternative:

```
table.getSelectionModel().select(null);
```

which calls the object `select`

if you want to see the whole code used/confirm for this

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {        
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Test Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));

        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        table.itemsProperty().get().add(new Person("Hans"));
        table.itemsProperty().get().add(new Person("Dieter"));

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        table.getSelectionModel().select(-1);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class Person {
        final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        Person(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() { return this.name; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could improve your answer with mentioning `getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(int index)` and implementing a "do unselect on click to selected item" as OP requests.

Comment: @thatslch  I tried your piece of code above. It does not deselect the previous selected row if I click on on it again.

Comment: @Dil I missunderstood you question: I thought how to clear was your problem.